# Get value from url on post method mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I needed to get a data from the url on my post method. I have this routing on my asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then on my Home Controller, under Get:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var id = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id");
}
```

And on Post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeNewNameHere(HomeModel homeModel)
{
    var id = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id");
}
```

My problem here is I need that id from the url on my post method. By debugging, I noticed that it gets the id on the get method, but when i post it, it returns me a null resulting to an error. So basically, RouteValues work on Get but not on my Post. Anything I missed here? Thanks!

Sample url:

```
http://localhost:1000/Controller/Action/12312121212
```

**EDIT**:

I also tried this but no luck:

```
var id = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

The form on the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeNewNameHere", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: what if you add it to the method signature, i.e. `Index(string id)` and `SomeNewNameHere(string id, HomeModel homeModel)`

Comment: Can you show us the form in your view?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `id` parameter to the post URL in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeNewNameHere", "Home",new { id = Model.ID}, FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It helped me solve my problem. Please see my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add and `int` `Id` property to your `HomeModel`

then in your view, within your form:

```
@Html.Hiddenfor(m => m.Id)
```

This will post the Id to your action method

Comment: This might be possible. But i'm wondering if there is any other way that I won't store it anymore like pulling it from url. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Ufuk Hacıoğulları, I came up with this solution on my form:

```
(Html.BeginForm("SomeNewNameHere", "Home",new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") }, FormMethod.Post))
```

So what happened here is it includes the id when it do a post.

Answer (score 0):

Your Querystring values and Form values are automatically sent to the ActionResult at the same time, and the ASP.Net MVC Model binder will attempt to bind everything that it can.

So your GET Index ActionResult should be;

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    // access id directly
}
```

And your POST Index ActionResult should be;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeNewNameHere(int id, HomeModel homeModel)
{
    // access id directly
}
```

So your URL needs to be `/Home/Index?id=1`

Comment: My URL can't contain `?id=1`. For some purposes, I only used `id` as sample but in reality, it is not. Thanks btw!

Comment: The Querystring could be anything. `/Home/Index?foobar=barfoo` for example, and then your ActionResult would be `ActionResult(string foobar, HomeModel homeModel)`